# text and image wrapping in latex tables

Tags: tables, graphics

I was trying to insert pictures with captions in a table in latex. I have read some posts here about adding pictures in the table using \raisebox. I tried something like

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 Query Structure & The most similar structure & The second most similar structure & The    third most similar structure \\
\hline
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{GS_Ade_PathwayA_I1A_B3LYP_631Gd}} &     \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{GS_Ade_PathwayA_I1A_B3LYP_631Gd}} & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{GS_Ade_PathwayA_I1A_G3MP2B3}} &\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{GS_Ade_PathwayA_I1A_G3B3}}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

It worked. But I want these pictures with captions. At first, I tried to add caption{} in raisebox directly like:

```
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{GS_Ade_PathwayA_I1A_B3LYP_631Gd} \caption{structure GS\_Ade\_PathwayA\_I1A\_B3LYP\_631Gd}}
```

I got error msg for writing latex like this. So I tired to put the captions in the next row with no \hline in between to work around.

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\label{table2}
\begin{center} %Note American spelling
\begin{tabular}{| p{0.25\textwidth} | p{0.25\textwidth} | p{0.25\textwidth} |   p{0.25\textwidth} |}
\hline
Query Structure & The most similar structure & The second most similar structure & The    third most similar structure \\
\hline
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{GS_Ade_PathwayA_I1A_B3LYP_631Gd}} & raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{GS_Ade_PathwayA_I1A_B3LYP_631Gd}} & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{GS_Ade_PathwayA_I1A_G3MP2B3}} &\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{GS_Ade_PathwayA_I1A_G3B3}} \\
GS\_Ade\_PathwayA\_I1A\_B3LYP\_631Gd.out1.ar &GS\_Ade\_PathwayA\_I1A\_B3LYP\_631Gd.out1.ar &GS\_Ade\_PathwayA\_I1A\_G3MP2B3.out1.ar &GS\_Ade\_PathwayA\_I1A\_G3B3.out1.ar \\
\hline
\caption{Results Table}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

By doing above, I got two problems with the result.

1. The pictures are not centered in each cell. Although I have set the height of the raisbox, the pictures are still closely attached to the upper cell edge.
2. I have set the width of each column to be 1/4 width of the \textwidth. It worked for the texts in the header. Some long text such as "The second most similar structure" was splited into two rows. However, for the text under the pictures, they were all overlapped. I think Latex consider it as a whole word, so it didn't split into multiple rows.

Can anyone suggest how to solve these problems?

Thank you.

Comment: Do these figures need to be numbered like a normal figure, possibly cited elsewhere in the doc and/or showing up in a list of figures, or are you merely content with getting unnumbered subtext that functions like a caption?

Comment: If would be better if these pictures can be cited elsewhere, but it also worked for me just getting these contents as unnumbered subtext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution only places unnumbered subtext below the figures, just using a separate figure row.  If there is no text on the same row with the figures, then a `\raisebox` approach is not required.  Since you didn't provide a minimum working example (MWE), I assumed that the figures were on a row by themselves.  I omitted `\hline` between the titles, the figures, and the subtext, so as to group them more nicely.  By using `p` columns, text wraps automatically.

As David pointed out, one must leave room for column padding separation, so in this case, I only made each column width `0.21\textwidth` to avoid overfilling the column width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{.21\textwidth}|p{.21\textwidth}|p{.21\textwidth}|p{.21\textwidth}|}
\hline
 Query Structure & The most similar structure & 
The second most similar structure & The    third most similar structure \\
\includegraphics[width=.21\textwidth]{GS_Ade_PathwayA_I1A_B3LYP_631Gd} &
\includegraphics[width=.21\textwidth]{GS_Ade_PathwayA_I1A_B3LYP_631Gd} & 
\includegraphics[width=.21\textwidth]{GS_Ade_PathwayA_I1A_G3MP2B3} &
\includegraphics[width=.21\textwidth]{GS_Ade_PathwayA_I1A_G3B3}\\
\scriptsize \url{GS_Ade_PathwayA_I1A_B3LYP_631Gd.out1.ar}
& \scriptsize next caption
& \scriptsize third caption
& \scriptsize last caption\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To answer the OP's follow-up, on how to add gap between an `\hline` and a subsequent row of `\includegraphics` images, which are otherwise flush with the `\hline`, there are many approaches.  The one I adopt is to use the `\addvbuffer[top_gap bottom_gap]{...}` macro from my `verbatimbox` package.  One merely need apply this to the tallest image of the row.  Here, I re-present the MWE with the `\hline`s added, and an `\addvbuffer` in place.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{.21\textwidth}|p{.21\textwidth}|p{.21\textwidth}|p{.21\textwidth}|}
\hline
Query Structure & The most similar structure & 
The second most similar structure & The    third most similar structure \\
\hline
\addvbuffer[4pt 0pt]{\includegraphics[width=.21\textwidth]{GS_Ade_PathwayA_I1A_B3LYP_631Gd}} &
\includegraphics[width=.21\textwidth]{GS_Ade_PathwayA_I1A_B3LYP_631Gd} &
\includegraphics[width=.21\textwidth]{GS_Ade_PathwayA_I1A_G3MP2B3} &
\includegraphics[width=.21\textwidth]{GS_Ade_PathwayA_I1A_G3B3}\\
\hline
\scriptsize \url{GS_Ade_PathwayA_I1A_B3LYP_631Gd.out1.ar}
& \scriptsize next caption
& \scriptsize third caption
& \scriptsize last caption\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `}{|p{.25\textwidth}|p{.25\textwidth}|p{.25\textwidth}|p{.25\textwidth}|}` is overfull by 8\tabcolsep + 5\arrayrulewidth

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Yeah, I knew that...  Will adjust

Comment: I guess I didn't explain my problem clearly. I knew by using p columns, texts will wraps automatically. But for my case, the text I want to put under the pictures is like "GS_Ade_PathwayA_I1A_B3LYP_631Gd.out1.ar".(some cases may even longer) It won't warps automatically. I think Latex consider it as a whole word, so it doesn't wrap it. They were all in one line and overlaps.

Comment: @user3293338 See revision.  You need the `url` package.

Comment: @user3293338 put `\linebreak[0]` after each `_` or anywhere else you want to allow a break (or url package as Steven just said, but that's optimised for breaking on / and . so you might need to change some of its defaults)

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much, Steven and David.

Comment: If I add \hline, I notice that the picture's upper edge is overlapped with the upper cell edge. How can leave some distance in  between like put the picture in the middle of the cell. Thank you.

Comment: @user3293338  That is a common problem.  I have added a remedy to my answer.

Comment: How to make the text also in the center of the cell for this case? It seems all the solutions I found here are not suiteble for centering the text for this case. Thank you.

Comment: @user3293338 horizontally or vertically center?  For horizontal, I think `\centering` in the cell would suffice.

Comment: @user3293338 for vertical centering, you can put it explicitly in a strutted `\parbox` if the cell is two lines or more, i.e., `\scriptsize \parbox{.21\textwidth}{\strut\url{GS_Ade_PathwayA_I1A_B3LYP_631Gd.out1.ar}\strut}` or `\centering\scriptsize\parbox{.21\textwidth}{next caption\\two lines}`.

Comment: Thank you, Steven. I have tried that. I'd like to mention one thing here in case someone may also suffer from this problem.( It took me really long time to find the solution.) It worked for all the cells except the cells in the last column. Because \centering cannot use with \\. You have to replace \\ with \tabularnewline otherwise you will get the error msg.

Comment: @user3293338 Thank you for reminding me of `\tabularnewline`.